# jquery - convert div text to input field

Tags: jquery

I have form with Divs inside.
Some of them contain texts and have data attribute (ie. data-name)

I'm trying to create JQUERY script that by clicking of a button get the all DIVs attribute and implant input field inside the div.

I'm not sure how the create array of the data attribute for each DIV.
I'll appreciate your help

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function(e) {
  var element = $(this);
  var data = $(element).parents(".item_edit").data();
  var fieldContent = convert_text_to_form_field(data)
  element.parents(".item").find(".item_edit").html(fieldContent);
});


// this function should get data array of attributes and return form field (input, textarea, etc)

function convert_text_to_form_field(data) {
  fieldValue = "** data something **"
  fieldName = "** data something **"
  fieldType = "** data something **"
  fieldRequire = "** data something **"
  maxFiles = "** data something **"

  switch (fieldType) {
    case "input":
      field = "<input type='text' name='" + fieldName + "' value='" + fieldValue + "' />";
      break;
    case "textarea":
      field = "<textarea type='text' name='" + fieldName + "'>" + fieldValue + "</textarea>";
      break;
    case "fileArray":
      field = "<input type='file' name='" + fieldName + "' class='multi well well-sm' maxlength='" + maxFiles + "' accept='gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp' />";
      break;
  };

  if (fieldRequire = 1)
    field = field + "<span>*</span>";
  return (field);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='#' method='post' id="4" class='item'>
  <div class='item-edit' data-type='fileArray' data-name='file[]' data-maxFiles='1'>LOGO HERE</div>
  <div class='item-edit' data-type='input' data-name='agnt[name]' data-require='1'>SOME NAME</div>
  <div class='item-edit' data-type='textarea' data-name='agnt[contact]'>SOME CONTACT</div>
  <div class='col-md-2 panel-menu'>
    <span class='edit_msg'></span>

    <a href='#' class='btn btn-success edit_save-btn hidden'>SAVE</a>
    <a href='#' class='btn btn-success edit-btn'>EDIT</a>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `.edit-btn` in HTML?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve]

Comment: @Karan - I edited the post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function(e) {
  var element = $(this);
  //var data = $(element).parents(".item_edit").data();
  //var fieldContent = convert_text_to_form_field(data)
  element.parents(".item").find(".item-edit").each((index, data) => convert_text_to_form_field($(data)));
});

function convert_text_to_form_field(data) {
  var field;
  var fieldValue = data.data("value") || "";
  var fieldName = data.data("name") || "";
  var fieldType = data.data("type") || "";
  var fieldRequire = data.data("require") || "";
  var maxFiles = data.data("maxFiles") || "";

  //console.log(fieldValue + '-' + fieldName + '-' + fieldType + '-' + fieldRequire + '-' + maxFiles);
  
  switch (fieldType) {
    case "input":
      field = "<input type='text' name='" + fieldName + "' value='" + fieldValue + "' />";
      break;
    case "textarea":
      field = "<textarea type='text' name='" + fieldName + "'>" + fieldValue + "</textarea>";
      break;
    case "fileArray":
      field = "<input type='file' name='" + fieldName + "' class='multi well well-sm' maxlength='" + maxFiles + "' accept='gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp' />";
      break;
  };

  if (fieldRequire == 1) {
    field = field + "<span>*</span>";
  }
  
  data.html(field);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='#' method='post' id="4" class='item'>
  <div class='item-edit' data-type='fileArray' data-name='file[]' data-maxFiles='1'>LOGO HERE</div>
  <div class='item-edit' data-type='input' data-name='agnt[name]' data-require='1'>SOME NAME</div>
  <div class='item-edit' data-type='textarea' data-name='agnt[contact]'>SOME CONTACT</div>
  <div class='col-md-2 panel-menu'>
    <span class='edit_msg'></span>
    <a href='#' class='btn btn-success edit_save-btn hidden'>SAVE</a>
    <a href='#' class='btn btn-success edit-btn'>EDIT</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank very much! just 1 thing - the value should come from the div attribute. it should come from the div content (<div></div>)

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery [replacewith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to resolve your issue.

Just grab the element with the identifier and replace the content with your `convert_text_to_form_field` function

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit_save-btn", function(e) {
  var element = $(this);
  var data = $(element).parents(".item_edit").data();
  var fieldContent = convert_text_to_form_field(data);
  $(".item").find("[data-type='" + data.fieldType + "']").replaceWith( fieldContent );
});
```